# Android HttpGet error on "specific url"

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask, http-get

Here is my code

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri[0]);
        Log.v("test","start RESPONSE");
        response = httpclient.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            Log.v("test","status complete");
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

When uri[0] = "http://www.google.com", it has no error and Log.v("test","status complete") show.
but when

`uri[0] = "http://best12t.gosoft.com/web_service/counter/CSTrack2.aspx?cli=focusgroup&cam=androidtest&1=W_S_UID&2=W_S_SC&3=W_S&5=W_S_DATE&7=www.gocorp.com&8=www.gocorp.com%2Ftc%2F&9=&10=W_S_IP&11=www.gocorp.com&12=www.gocorp.com%2F&13=&14=website&15=W_S&16=W_S&17=W_S&19=windows&20=Win%207(x64)&21=1&22=9.0&23=1366x768&24=1&25=1&6=CRM%20%26%20%u6578%u4F4D%u884C%u92B7%u7684%u9818%u5C0E%u8005%20-%20MIGO%20CORP%20%u529F%u5178%u96C6%u5718%20&1375088741345"`

error happen,and my virtual device stop and appear "unfortunately,app has stop".
In addition, Log.v("test","start RESPONSE") doesn't show on my LogCat.

I've tried another app to enter this url on web browser, it work ,and I can get this message from my web.

So is it any limitation when using httpget?

Thanks for help!